# Difference between char array[] and char array[10]

Tags: c

```
char array[] = "string";
```

or

```
char array[10] = "string";
```

what's the difference in C and which is a better way?

Since both works then why limiting the array by putting a value inside the []

Never mind, thanks

Comment: I think the question is more, why didn't you do any research?! This question was asked many times before!

Comment: And what have you found? If you didn't found anything, i think you want to learn how to use google

Comment: [How to initialize an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c), though not a duplicate, lists both.

Answer (score 2):

> what's the difference in C and which is a better way?

`char array[]="string";` declares `array` as an array of `7` `char`s and initialize it with `string`.

`char array[10]="string";` declares `array` as an array of `10` `char`s and initialize it with `string`.

You can use either depending as per the requirements. For ex: If you go with first, then string concatenation is not possible. If you go with second then a string of length `3` (including `'\0'`) can be concatenated to it.

Comment: @; Gopi; In `char array[] = "string";`,  `"string"` is an initializer. If the length of array is not specified, then compiler uses the length of initializer to calculate the length of the array.

Comment: You can't use this syntax without initializer.

Comment: @Gopi; Your welcome. One thing I would like to mention that you can use `char array[]` in a function parameter.

Comment: Since both works then why limiting the array by putting a value inside the []

Comment: @Sumon; May be the initializer is long enough to calculate its length correctly and you want to avoid that sudden accident caused by the wrong  array length specified.